# User has full access to target, but still receives "Mount Error(13): Permission Denied"

Tags: server, mount, permissions, samba, sharing

I'm working on mounting the E drive of one of my Windows servers so I can work with its data from a Linux server.  I can get the thing to mount if I use my credentials (domain admin), but I can't get it to mount if I use a service account.  The service account in question currently has full access to the remote drive it's trying to mount.

My goal here to is to have the drive auto-mount in the Ubuntu server on every boot using the service account specified, controlling it's security from Windows so it can only read.  Here's what I'm working with...

Mount command:

```
mount.cifs //<fqdn of server>/E$ /mnt/backups/sql -o credentials=/root/.credentials/windows_mount,vers=3.0
```

`/root/.credentials/windows_mount` (works):

```
domain=domain.com
username=myusername
password=mypassword.
```

`/root/.credentials/windows_mount` (does not work):

```
domain=domain.com
username=svc_replication
password=servicepassword.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the troubleshooting section of the CIFS mounting guide?
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently#Login_errors